# How to apply an Excel-formula on a dynamic array using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to apply a few excel formulas on different dynamic excel-ranges E.g.  trim, custom-format, log, exp ...etc. 
I would like to
-Avoid iteration 
-Generate a range output of strings

Here is an example: =exp(input)

[image]

I tried, without success, the VBA function:

```
Sub test()
Dim OutputRange As Range
Set OutputRange = Math.Exp(Range("inputRange"))
End Sub
```

Any idea how to achieve this with VBA in a clean and simple way? Perhaps in the same fashion as the R-function "apply"

Comment: If you want the output as a text string and not a Number Format mask then you will need to iterate the cells and use `Format()` in vba on each cell.

Comment: I do need the output as string. However, I would like to use range and avoid iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Recordning a macro is really the trick in any formatting issues in Excel.

Thus, after recording one and doing the formats, you may see this:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Range("C6").Select
End Sub
```

with some clearing out of the Selection and using the defined range, it becomes this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    [ExcelTestRange].NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End Sub
```

**Another**, probably better option is to build the formula in Excel through VBA. It is done like this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    [ExcelTestRange].Formula = "=TEXT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)),""0,000.00"")"
End Sub
```

The tricky part is to come up with the formula correctly, especially if you are not using English Excel, but something else. The easiest trick is to select the already working formula and run the following code:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim selectedFormula  As String
    Dim parenthesis  As String

    parenthesis = """"

    selectedFormula = Selection.Formula
    selectedFormula = Replace(selectedFormula, """", """""")

    selectedFormula = parenthesis & selectedFormula & parenthesis
    Debug.Print selectedFormula

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you be kind and rewrite the code using another Excel function instead of the format function?

Comment: @DKK - sure, I am as kind as a kind can be :)

Comment: Your profile picture suggests "you are as kind as a fox can be" ;-) Thanks I am having a look into it !

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with EXP function (other functions can apply as well)

```
Sub Test_Range_Formula()

    Dim inputRange As Range: Set inputRange = Range("inputRange")
    Dim aux As Range : Set aux = Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(UBound(inputRange.Value, 1) - 1, 0).Address)

    aux.FormulaArray = "=EXP(inputRange)+1"

End Sub
```